# Incrementally load data from SQL Server views into D365

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm-365

I'm implementing a SSIS package where I want to incrementally load data from SQL Server to D365. From source to staging, we are loading data to tables with 15 minutes frequency. This incremental data is based on the `DATELASTMAINT` (Last Date Maintenance). We have created a few views on top of these tables. We are loading data from these views into D365 entities.

But in this workflow, we just want to incrementally load data into D365 as it's taking a long time for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. We are using KingswaySoft for D365 data connection.

I tried couple of scenarios to incrementally get data, but couldn't succeed. What is the best way to incrementally fetch data from views (which are based on multiple tables) and push that data into D365?

Comment: When you say that you couldn't succeed, can you please elaborate on what you mean by that? Is that because your source view data is made of multiple entities, which you don't know how to split or normalize them into the format of the target entity or something else?

Comment: Yes, source view data is made of multiple entities/tables. 

I tried way to get only increment data (truncate and load delta records only) to tables which are getting used in the views, but all tables wont have delta records for that time frequency which is providing wrong output by the view.

Another option I tried to get only incremental data for main table in the view but it didn't work as some fields of view are from other tables which doesn't updated in that time frequency.

Comment: Based on your description, it is more of an issue on your source side which you don't have a proper incremental reading strategy for some entities. If your source system has such timestamp fields, it will be relatively straightforward. If not, you could maintain a staging table that you use to perform a query that returns the delta. In such cases, it is not a problem on the D365 side (or KingswaySoft). Such delta is necessary if your table is large. Otherwise, you may use the Upsert action with the Ignore Unchanged Fields option enabled which does a certain degree of incremental writing.

Comment: My main concern here is how to get delta records from Views as views consists of multiple tables. Because we can apply logic on tables for delta records but all tables are not getting updated at same time which are getting use in the view. So I have to make changes to views to provide the delta records only.